# Consider mysql pivot table?

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

```
SELECT T.fromP,T.toP,T.value,T.type FROM CELLPROPERTYFACT F 
INNER JOIN DIM_TIMING T ON T.timingID = F.timingID 
WHERE T.cellID = '1' 
AND (type = 'cell_rise' or type = 'cell_fall');

+-------+------+----------+-----------+<br>
| fromP | toP  | value    | type      |<br>
+-------+------+----------+-----------+<br>
| ZN    | A1   | 0.168072 | cell_fall |<br>
| ZN    | A1   | 0.176866 | cell_rise |<br>
| ZN    | A2   | 0.177704 | cell_fall |<br>
| ZN    | A2   | 0.176244 | cell_rise |<br>
+-------+------+----------+-----------+<br>
```

I get above result...is it possible to make it become

```
+-------+------+------------+-----------+<br>
| fromP | toP  | cellRise   | cellFall  |<br>
+-------+------+------------+-----------+<br>
| ZN    | A1   | 0.176866   | 0.168072  |<br>
| ZN    | A2   | 0.176244   | 0.177704  |<br>
+-------+------+----------+-------------+<br>
```

**Edit:**

```
SELECT T.fromP,T.toP,value,type,
case when type = "cell_rise" then value end as CellRise,
case when type = 'cell_fall' then value end as CellFall, 
FROM CELLPROPERTYFACT F 
INNER JOIN DIM_TIMING T on T.timingID = F.timingID 
WHERE F.cellID = '1' 
AND (T.type='cell_Rise' or T.type='cell_fall') ;

 +-------+------+----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| fromP | toP  | value    | type      | CellRise            | CellFall            |
+-------+------+----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| ZN    | A1   | 0.168072 | cell_fall |                NULL | 0.16807200014591217 |
| ZN    | A1   | 0.176866 | cell_rise | 0.17686599493026733 |                NULL |
| ZN    | A2   | 0.177704 | cell_fall |                NULL | 0.17770400643348694 |
| ZN    | A2   | 0.176244 | cell_rise | 0.17624400556087494 |                NULL |
+-------+------+----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

This is the best i can get...how to merge the same fromP and toP? if using group by only can show either cell rise or cell fall

Comment: Add a GROUP BY after where clause, lets say on toP `GROUP BY T.toP`

Comment: Not sure why @Kumar deleted their answer. Looks more or less right to me.